# Is there any .NET API to get all the firewall rules

Tags: c#

We have an application which add some rules to firewall. We need to retrieve the rules of firewall so that we can check whether the rule exists in the firewall.
I am using C#.

Comment: [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19003/The-managed-classes-to-read-Windows-Firewall-confi) you can find an old article on reading the property settings of the Windows Vista Firewall. Don't know if it is still valid

Comment: Does this work for all the OS ????

Answer (score 4):

Search the Firewall rules using a rule Name and remove it:

```
public static void RemoveFirewallRules(string RuleName)
{
    try
    {
        Type tNetFwPolicy2 = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2");
        INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy2 = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(tNetFwPolicy2);
        var currentProfiles = fwPolicy2.CurrentProfileTypes;               

        // List of rules
        // List<INetFwRule> RuleList = new List<INetFwRule>();

        foreach (INetFwRule rule in fwPolicy2.Rules)
        {
            // Add a rule to list
            // RuleList.Add(rule);
            // Console.WriteLine(rule.Name);
            if (rule.Name.IndexOf(RuleName) != -1)
            {
                // Remove a rule
                INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));                     
                firewallPolicy.Rules.Remove(rule.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(rule.Name + " has been deleted from the Firewall Policy");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception r)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error deleting a Firewall rule");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to add extra references to assemblies providing the INetFwPolicy2 interface, you can use [the dynamic class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) in C# to reflect the "HNetCfg.FwPolicy2" type. See this working code:

```
Type tNetFwPolicy2 = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2");
dynamic fwPolicy2 = Activator.CreateInstance(tNetFwPolicy2) as dynamic;                          
IEnumerable Rules = fwPolicy2.Rules as IEnumerable;
foreach (dynamic rule in Rules)
  {
  if (rule.Name=="My firewall rule")
    {

    }                              
  }
```

Note that using the dynamic object in this way requires a reference to Microsoft.CSharp assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an idea from this code.

```
INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy2 = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(typeFWPolicy2);

List<INetFwRule> RuleList = new List<INetFwRule>();

foreach (INetFwRule rule in fwPolicy2.Rules)
{
  RuleList.Add(rule);
}
```

Comment: There is more professional way to get list:
fwPolicy2.Rules.Cast<INetFwRule>().ToList()

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:
INetFwPolicy2 is a .Net interface to manage Firewall rules [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
INetFwPolicy2 has a rules collection contains all ruls of this policy.
You can query the Rules collection with Lambda, as follow:

```
INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
fwPolicy2.Rules.OfType<INetFwRule>.Select....
```

and all other Lambda extensions.

Comment: You should really improve this answer by showing the type of fwPolicy2, preferably the fully qualified name, and preferably with a link to its documentation.