# How do I view Windows Firewall rules with ASP.NET Core / 5 / 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I see the following code everywhere on StackOverflow. Supposedly it gives you access to the Windows Firewall API and lets you view and set firewall rules, etc:

```
var firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
```

For example:

> [Is there any .NET API to get all the firewall rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342260/is-there-any-net-api-to-get-all-the-firewall-rules)
>
> [Can I get the firewall's status by c# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179441/can-i-get-the-firewalls-status-by-c-sharp-code)

However, the type `INetFwPolicy2` is not recognized by my ASP.NET 6 application, and I haven't been able to find what namespace it would be in.

Is the Windows Firewall API still available in ASP.NET 6? If not, how can I go about viewing Windows Firewall rules? This goes for ASP.NET Core 3.1 and 5 as well.

Comment: It isn't in any (standard) namespace; that's an interface that would be made available through a COM interop library, since `HNetCfg.FwPolicy2` is a COM class. This is not a .NET-specific API. .NET Core 6 (or more accurately .NET Core 3+) does have support for COM interop, but I have no idea how far along that implementation is or how it's properly used.

Comment: This is tagged ASP.Net. Typically, an ASP.Net application should not run with permissions that would allow firewall rules to be queried.

Comment: There's also a `WindowsFirewallHelper` nuget available.

Comment: But I agree to @EricJ. A web application that sets firewall rules sounds like a major security risk.